# Get html code from Android

Tags: android, jsoup

I have a json file for countries , cities  as below
{
    "id": 1,
    "Country": "Country1",
    "City": "City1",
  }
and also have php file for get specific countries .

Php side returns html like 
`<ul><h4>42</h4>
<li>ENGLAND</li>
<li>LONDON</li>
<ul>` this.(  `<br>` not included ).

From browser argument passing for specific countries working very well so no problem at that.
My actual problem is I can't retrieve that html codes from android studio.
I am using an Async task to do it.In My doInBackground function.

This one for using jsoup

```
protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
String server_url="http://192.168.1.33/myphp/GetCountry.php";
            server_url+="?Id="+et;
            StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();
            try{

               Document doc = Jsoup.connect(server_url).get();
              Elements elements=doc.select("ul li");
                for(Element element:elements){
                    System.out.println(element);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);

            }

            return null;
        }
```

this one for httpurlconnection

```
protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
    String server_url="http://192.168.1.33/myphp/GetCountry.php";
                server_url+="?Id="+et;
                StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();
                try{
                    URL url=new URL(server_url);
                    HttpURLConnection con= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    con.connect();

                   BufferedReader bf=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                  for(String returned;(returned=bf.readLine()) !=null;   ){

                      stringBuilder.append(returned);
                  }
                  bf.close();
                    System.out.println(stringBuilder);

                    }

                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e);

                }

                return null;
            }
```

> I have tried HttpURLConnection method and Jsoup method.But two of all
>   doesn't working.It just return `<ul></ul>` . What can i do ?

Comment: `I can't retrieve that html codes from android studio. ` Of course not. Android Studio will not contact your server.

Comment: Oh you're right sorry.I am using two  of them seperately.First using httpurlconnection (JSON things commented).Then  vice versa.

Comment: `server_url+="?Id="+et;` What does the php script return if `et` contains an invalid value?

Comment: I have edited my code for your request sir.

Comment: et is coming from Edittext .User give an input for us.And we send to php file.

Comment: Im not interested where it comes from. I want to know the value. And you telling if it is a valid value. Is 123456789 valid? Which value did you use?

Comment: `And we send to php file` ???????????????

Comment: `What does the php script return if et contains an invalid value?`

Comment: Between certain numbers like 1-82 . The other values not valid.We send to php file that server_url (composed with server_url+="?Id="+et;) mean    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(server_url).get(); here goes to server.

Comment: if et contains an invalid value return  <ul></ul>

Comment: And that is what you received. So you sent an invalid number i conclude!?

Comment: Ohhh ı know my mistake  now sir.Thank you very much.

Comment: You are obliged to tell your mistake.

Comment: Yep i am sending edittext directly to server.But I should get text of editttext.And now works perfectly.

Comment: I painted your head. I am so mad.So sorrry

Comment: Send me the picture  ;-).

Comment: https://i.hizliresim.com/qJX40V.png On the bottom line. Thank you sir.I hope some day u get tons of bitcoins then stop developing :D

Comment: Please consider writing a generalized answer for other users with a similar problem or removing the question, since it is resolved. Thanks.